# Apple Keychain does not have private key to export

Tags: certificate, private-key, signing, pkpass

I've created a Certificate Signing Request (CSR) file using KeyChain on an iMac and MacBook. I have successfully uploaded the CSR file to Apple for generating a Pass Type ID certificate. I can download and install the certificate to the machine the CSR file was generated from.
The problem now is I cannot export the certificate AND the private key because there is no private key associated with the certificate! Very strange considering the CSR file came from this machine.

I have followed the Apple guide and they make no mention to this potentially being a problem so there's no troubleshooting help there.

I do not know what's going wrong here so please shed light on this if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved
The Common Name had to match the name used in the id.